# Are the 2.7 and 3.3 python versions compatible?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pipe

I want to work with Blender (python 3.3) but sometimes I need to use VTK functions (python 2.7). I do not want to rewrite all the functions of VTK nor fall back to the 2.7 version.

Is there a way to create a pipe between the two versions to pass some arguments from Blender to VTK, using VTK functions and send the result (regardless of formatting) to Blender ?

Or am I too greedy ?

Comment: Sure. You can create a pipe between _any_ two programs, and send data between them serialized to any format they can both understand. JSON, HDF5, Python pickle protocol 2, an XML or ASN.1 language, whatever makes sense for your app.

Comment: Their output are compatible; the code is not

Comment: One more question, if a pipe is created. The program will be synchronous or asynchronous ? Or is there many ways to create pipe ? I want it synchronous